# Spotlight keeps re-indexing Time Machine volumes (days on end)

Tags: time-machine, spotlight

Spotlight keeps re-indexing all external Time Machine volumes (Catalina, iMac 2020), keeping the drives busy, literally for days on end. This is slowing disk access to a crawl, such that a backup takes very long to complete. Also, wear and tear on hardware is considerable over time.

I understand Spotlight is essential for Time Machine, but this full re-index should not be necessary, since nothing changes between mounts.

One drive kept re-indexing for two and a half days and eventually settled. Now it's starting over with the next drive. With three drives in the array and another kept off-site, I expect this to stay busy for a week or so.

What's even more disturbing, it also re-indexes backup volumes of different machines, which it has no business in doing.

This didn't happen to me before and the drives have been in use for years. What is causing this re-indexing in the first place?

Comment: You might find some crucial clues in this Apple Communities Discussions post: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251263201

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks, I already tried that to no avail. It seems like for this user, indexing ran to completion while he was trying to solve the issue. So probably more coincidence rather than causation.

Comment: @Anders in Monterey, Apple seems to have specifically disabled the steps discussed there. It's like they really want us to not use TimeMachine or Spotlight. But Spotlight cannot be disabled without disabling system-integrity. Yay!